# SEND_SMS permission | Dialog message is saying this App may view sms

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat

I am using the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

When the Android ask for permission for API >= 23, a dialog come with the message as:

> "Allow AppName to send and view SMS messages?"

My clients are concerned that I am reading their SMS messages. 
Any guess on tackling this case, please?

I don't have READ_SMS permission.

I have no interest to change the text what it displayed, rather a reason or two to know why the message is saying I CAN VIEW TOO?

Comment: As you said, API >= 23 requires run-time permission from the user in order to tighten the security. Whats your requirement actually ? Is your intention to bypass this dialog ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam - It is clear from my question that why it is asking for "VIEW SMS MESSAGES" when I just need to send sms and not read sms?

Answer (score 3):

> I don't have READ_SMS permission.

That does not matter.

> a reason or two to know why the message is saying I CAN VIEW TOO?

The user grants rights at the permission-group level. The SMS permission group includes the ability to send and read SMS messages.

> My clients are concerned that I am reading their SMS messages

Then perhaps elect not to send SMS messages directly on Android 6.0+ devices, but instead use `ACTION_SENDTO` and the user's chosen SMS client.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change this default text but you can show your custom dialog, before requesting the permission, with explanation why this permission is required. Take a look at: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request)